# Is there a way to create Roxygen2 source code from documentation (.rd)?

Tags: r, roxygen2

I have to modify a package in R that i wrote time ago and i would like to add easily more functionalities using roxygen2. How can i translate the .rd files in my source code?
Help is much appreciated

Comment: Maybe you're looking for the package `Rd2roxygen`? http://yihui.name/Rd2roxygen/

Comment: yes, it worked. Thanks and sorry for the duplicate